# Bug in MVC Core 2 - Stored Procedures returns null

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, output

how do I report a bug to MVC Core2 team, the stored procedure Output Parameter returns null,

Here is my code

```
var p = new SqlParameter
{
    ParameterName = "token",
    DbType = System.Data.DbType.String,
    Size = 100, Value = "Sarah",
    Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output
};
var z = p.SqlValue;
var resp = await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("exec dbo.yourstoredprocedure {0}, {1}","test", p); 
var y = p.SqlValue;
var x = p.Value;
```

resp is always -1 and x and y are both null, the stored procedure is simply

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[yourstoredprocedure] 
( @varone nvarchar(max),
@vartwo nvarchar(50) OUTPUT)
AS
 insert into test (two, three) select  @varone, @vartwo'
SET @vartwo =  scope_identity()
return @vartwo;
```

Comment: You're not declaring `@varfour`. I expect it's returning *`NULL`* as the SP is generating an error. Also, you have an unclosed quote at the end of your `INSERT`. You have `@vartwo` as an `OUTPUT` parameter, but you don't assign any values to it within the SP, and you then use `RETURN` (don't use `RETURN`) on `@varfour` (which, as I said, is undeclared). The SP is simply full of syntax errors, I doubt it's a problem at all with your application.

Comment: apologies, I have corrected the sp, however thats not the problem as the return value is always null

Comment: Always assume you screwed up. That's good advice for even seasoned programmers. When you start blaming stuff on the framework you stop looking for solutions. Particularly in this case, a generic bug that would cause SPs to return null, would be so pervasive that there would already be an issue regarding it and a fix would be fast-tracked. Given that it's open-source and there's only millions of developers using this stuff on a daily basis, a fix would very likely come from the community, probably as part of the issue. In other words, it's almost assuredly *not* a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in the comments, your SP is full of Syntax errors. It should probably look more like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[yourstoredprocedure] @varone nvarchar(max),
                                             @vartwo nvarchar(50),
                                             @varfour int OUTPUT AS --What happened to @varthree ?


    INSERT INTO test (two, three)
    VALUES (@varone, @vartwo);
    SET @varfour = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
GO
```

Comment: Also the calling function seems bad, should be something like `ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("EXEC dbo.yourstoredprocedure 'test', 'test', @varfour OUTPUT", p)` based off your proc.

Comment: Sorry this is late, I have been out of town for the bank hols. I said there was a bug, because my colleagues are using insert statements which I dont like, I rather use SP, they showed me a few posts online which clearly says there was a bug. I tried to report on MS website but it says it was retired, here's a github conversation https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9277

Comment: Mark G - the your suggestion returns an error ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("EXEC dbo.yourstoredprocedure 'test', 'test', @varfour OUTPUT", p)

Comment: @Ehi I still very much doubt this is a bug in MCV, like Chris suggested. You still have a Syntax error in your SQL (there's a unclosed single quote (`'`) at the end of your `INSERT` statement) & you're using @vartwo, as both an `INPUT` and `OUTPUT` parameter in a very odd way with conflicting datatypes (`SCOPE_IDENTITY` will be returning an `int`, so why are you assigning it to a `varchar`)? You're also assigning a value to your `OUTPUT` parameter and then also using `RETURN` (don't use `RETURN`). The problem is going to be thee syntax errors & odd usage, not a bug. You need to fix your code.